# What is the solution to this problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm sorry I can't be more specific in the title.
I have this exercise I can't solve by myself, I've tried many times and I never get the right answer:
$[(\frac{1}{a^2}-b^2):(\frac{1}{a}+b)]^{-1}$
This is the answer:
$\frac{a}{1-ab}$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think when you write $[(1/a^2 - b^2):(1/a+b)]^{-1}$ what you really mean is $$\left(\frac{\frac{1}{a^2} - b^2}{\frac{1}{a} + b}\right)^{-1}$$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint:* The difference of squares formula is: $x^2-y^2 =(x-y)(x+y)$. Don't forget that $\frac{1}{a^2} = \left( \frac{1}{a} \right)^2$.

Comment: Hadn't noticed, thanks!! :D